# 'questions' and 'answers' with multiple answers

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, rdbms-agnostic

This question is related to this post:
[SQL design for survey with answers of different data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764469/sql-design-for-survey-with-answers-of-different-data-types)

I have a survey app where most questions have a set of answers that are 1-5. Now we have to do questions that could have a variety of different answer types -- numeric, date, string, etc. Thanks to suggestions from stack, I went with a string column to store answers. Some questions are multiple choice, so along with the table 'questions', I have a table 'answers' which has the set of possible answers for a question.

Now: how should I store answers for a question that is "pick all that apply"? Should I make a child table that is "chosen_answers" or something like that? Or should the answers table have a 'chosen' column that indicates that a respondent chose that answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a possible solution is a UsersAnswers table with 4 columns: primary key, user's id, question's id, and answer's id

with multiple entries for any questions where more than one answer can be selected

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions.

1. Normalize your database, and create a table called `question_answer`, or something that fits more in line with the nomenclature of your schema. This is how I would lay it out.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE question_answer (
       id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
       user_id INT NOT NULL,
       question_id INT NOT NULL,
       answer_id INT NOT NULL
   );
   ```
2. Create five columns in your `answers` table, each of which refers to a specific answer. In MySQL I would use set these columns up as `bit(1)` values.

IMHO, unless you see the number of choices changing, I would stick with option 2. It's a faster option and will most likely also save you space.

Answer (score 0):

As you're not going to have many options selected I'd be tempted to store the answers as a comma-separated list of values in your string answer column.

If the user is selecting their answers from a group of checkboxes on the web page with the question (assuming it is a web app) then you'll get back a comma-separated list from there too.  (Although you won't just be able to compare the lists as strings since the answer "red,blue" is the same as "blue,red".)

Comment: Yes, this is very tempting, :D though Jimmy's looks like the right one.

Comment: This idea struck me also, but it seems problematic when I try to run aggregating reports -- if I wanted to get the unique values and their respective counts for a set of surveys, that would involved some majro string parsing.

Comment: If you did want to run a report like "Most common wrong answers for pick-all-that-apply questions" this could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, (And I've seen cases where this was how questions like this were scored as well), is to treat each possible answer as a separate Yes/No question, and record the testee's response (Chose it, or didn't) as a boolean...

Answer (score 0):

these survey questions always have one, universal answer: **it depends on what you want to do with the answers when you're done.**

for example, if all you want to to is keep a record of each individual answer (and never do any totaling or find all users that answered question x with answer y), then the simplest design is to denormalize the answers in to a serialized field.

if you need totals, you can probably also get away with denormalized answers in to a serialized table if you calculate the totals in a summary table and update the values when a quiz is submitted.

so for your specific question, **you need to decide if it's more useful to your final product to store 5 when you mean "all of the above"** or if it's more useful to have each of the four options individually selected.

Comment: We'll want to run reports that sum up the counts of answers for given time periods ( and other attributes) . We don't have an 'all of the above' question, but I can easily forsee a "pick all ( read: any ) that apply"