# Primary Key and ER models

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship

Say i have an ER model

```
 _____________
|     E2      |
|_____________|
  |    |    |
  |    |    |
 A21* A22  A23*
```

where the A21 and A23 are primary keys.

Would this mean the primary key for E2 will be

PRIMARY KEY(A21, A23)?

If so, then what is the difference of the diagram below.

```
 _____________
|  E2         |
|_____________|
  |    |    |
  |    |    |
  []---|----[]---[]
  |    |    |
  |    |    |
 A21* A22  A23*
```

where the [] are representation of a combination of primary keys.
is this the same as the previous diagram and the primary key being
PRIMARY KEY (A21, A23)?

Then, based on the first diagram, should there be SQL code, can the statement
REFERENCES E2(A21) and REFERENCES E2(A23) exist?
Or do we have to always reference all the primary keys in a table?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Are you using ER to capture data analysis or database design? The same diagramming tool can be used for either. Some people don't make a distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognise the diagram notation you are using (designating keys with asterisks). Typically in an ER diagram key attributes are underlined (Chen notation) or are separated from other attributes by a line (IDEF1X).

One of the limitations with most ER notations is that they don't make it easy to show multiple candidate keys. Often only one key (the "primary key") per entity is shown. So at a guess I would say that if you have multiple key attributes shown on your diagram then they are probably all part of the same compound key.

A foreign key is only supposed to reference an entire candidate key, not parts of a key.

Answer (score 0):

The image is originally from **[this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey/1764901#1764901)**, I will use it to illustrate few basic points.

1. Foreign keys reference full primary keys.
2. ER is quite good at representing composite keys.
3. There are quite a few nice ER tools available (some open source) -- use one.

Take a look at the `Answer` table

```
create table Answer (
      SurveyID        integer
    , QuestionID      integer
    , OfferedAnswerID integer
    , PersonID        integer
    , OtherText       varchar (2000)
);

alter table Answer
    add constraint pk_answer
                   primary key (SurveyID, QuestionID, OfferedAnswerID, PersonID)

  , add constraint fk2_answer
                   foreign key (SurveyID, QuestionID, OfferedAnswerID)
                   references Survey_Question_Answer (SurveyID, QuestionID, OfferedAnswerID)

  , add constraint fk1_answer
                   foreign key (PersonID) references Person (PersonID)
;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

assuming i understand your question correctly the sql for the table would be

CREATE TABLE AKS.E2
(
  a21  NUMBER,
  a22  NUMBER,
  a23  NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE AKS.E2 ADD (
  CONSTRAINT E2_PK
 PRIMARY KEY
 (a21, a23));

you can have foreign key contraints like REFERENCES E2(A21) or REFERENCES E2(A23) even though they reference partial keys of a compund primary key.

Comment: I don't think you can reference only a part of a primary key. [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) "The columns in the referencing table must be the primary key or other candidate key in the referenced table." With which DBMS would you do that?

Comment: Ah okay, so therefore, should we use the first table, statements REFERENCES E2(A21) and REFERENCES E2(A23) cannot exist right pascal?

Comment: in standard SQL and in most DBMSs you cannot create referential constraints that reference part of a compound key. They have to reference exactly the full list of columns in a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: Your DDL doesn't work because you are trying to create a PRIMARY KEY on nullable columns, which doesn't work (just in case anyone else has tried it and got confused :).