# storing survey results - Mysql or NoSQL?

Tags: mongodb, survey, nosql

I am building a survey application where users can create surveys on the fly.
I am looking for suggestions on how to store the data for each survey.

I can save the survey results in the form of a database table that looks like:

[Database design for a survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey)

Are nosql databases like mongodb a better fit for this scenario?

I have never used a nosql database and do not know the learning curve to get this done.

Are there any resources?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like:

- Your database structure is relatively simple
- Your database structure is strict, i.e. you know the types of fields in advance
- Your database structure is unlikely to change over time, and if it does, you can easily convert
- You don't seem to have versioned objects
- Replication is not an issue
- Performance is not an issue

Therefore, I'd recommend using a traditional SQL database as long as these assumptions hold.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently surveying my lab to gauge the electricity consumption of the devices and the lab. I am considering google spreadsheet! Primarily because it's so easy to use the google analytics to analyze your results.

I am surveying on a small scale. I don't know the scale of your survey, so it'd be wrong to recommend Google Spreadsheet for a medium-large scale survey.