# nHibernate: How to map a property that can be of any type?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I´m have a class like this:

```
public class Answer
{
    virtual public int Number { get; set; }
    virtual public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The `Value` property is typed as `object` because for a yes/no question it will hold a `bool` value, for a multiple choice question it will hold an `int` value and for an open question it will hold a `string` value.

I intend to persist such a class in a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 table, being the `Value` stored in a `varbinary` column (not sure yet this is a good idea).

How to map such a class in nHibernate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I will confirm that your varbinary is not a good idea. Please consider revising your schema to something along the lines of the accepted answer for this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey It is much more 3NF-friendly, flexible, and more easily mappable to .Net POCOs.

Comment: @KyleHale: thanks for the linkm Kyle, I guess I have my answer already. I will accept the other one because it follows the same idea, but I greatly appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just have three different possible types for Value, consider making four different Answer classes- a base class (Answer), and three subclasses (AnswerInt, AnswerString, AnswerBool).  You can then do one of the standard mapping techniques- table-per-hierarchy or table-per-class.