# Foreign Key Constratins on primary key of one table to 2 columns of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables, `User` and `Questions`.

```
User 
    ID     
    Security_Question_Id_First  
    Security answer_First  
    Security_question_ID_Second  
    Security_Answer_Second

Questions
    ID     
    Security Questions
```

I need to have foreign key constrains on Security_question_Id_First and Id of Questions table and Security_question-Id-Second and Id of Questions table.

Currently, I have the User and Questions table created with User having only  Security_Question_Id_First  Security answer _First apart from Id. The foreign constraint between Security_Question_Id_First and Id of questions table exists.When I try to add a foreign constraint with Security_question_ID_Second  and ID of questions table, It throws an error.Can you advise as to how to go about adding foreign constraints between 2 columns of one table(user) and primary key of another (questions)

Comment: To improve your question add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for the two tables in question, add the SQL you run to add the constraints, and add the error you receive.

Comment: Generally it does not cause error. Can you show us the exact error?

Comment: This is becasue you shoudl not ever have a structure like this in a database. You should havea child table  UserSecurityquestion. Anytime you name  columns with things like XXX1, XXX2, that indicates that you need a related table instead.

Comment: @HLGEM You're right, but you don't get errors for bad practice. Two columns FKing to the same column is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys. The error that is was getting was in the User table the default value of the security_question_id-second was 0 and when the foreign constraint was being created the questions table was searched to see whether the primary key had a value of 0 and due to this I was getting the error "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" .  I have taken HLGEM's advice and lookinginto the structure defined in    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey.