# Is my database design a bad implementation of a database?

Tags: database, database-design

I want to assign the boss to the person in the database but I don't know if it will loop the database. If I make a relation between the person and the boss will this loop the database (one person has one boss and the company has many bosses)?

The person table is a normal person. Unemployed or employed. The database is centered around the person where the person can work at a company hence the non-identifying relationship. The person can also take the survey. That is why I want to know the answer the person took on the survey (if they decided to take it) and the boss of the person if s/he works at a company.

Also, same thing in the survey. I want to assign the answer given in the survey to the person.

[image: Database design]

As you can see, Person_Survey and Person_Company are a many to many structure. Is there some better way of implementing this database?

I don't know if it's a bad implementation. The design i'm trying to implement is this:

[image: intended design]

The new design that I implemented is the next shown figure (I don't know if it is a correct way to implement) where the boss and company table are many to many and one person can work with more than one boss in more than one company.

[image]

If there is something wrong with my question please put why and not just vote as bad. Thank you!

Comment: Correct data modeling requires deep understanding of the subject area. You have not provided enough details. There is nothing called 'loop the database'. It is not clear what is a 'person'? Is she an employee of the same company the 'boss' is in? In that case, they are both 'Employees'. I also suggest you look at the Answer part as its not probably correct. This example may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey

Comment: I added this: The person table is a normal person. Unemployed or employed. The database is centered around the person where the person can work at a company hence the non-identifying relationship. The person can also take the survey. That is why I want to know the answer the person took on the survey (if they decided to take it) and the boss of the person if s/he works at a company. 
I am looking at the link you sent me also, thanks

Comment: But if a person is  a any person, how can you know his boss id? Take my case as an example, you may ask me my company name, and generate an id for me in the database, but how would you find my boss id?

Comment: That is why i'm having so much trouble with this. I am trying to make it so that the the boss is assigned to the person is s/he works at a company. When I try to get back all the data related to the person, at the point where I get to fetching the data of the boss I get the first boss in that company in the register not, the one that is the actual boss. Since it is one company has many bosses and the person table does not need the boss to be correctly normalized I am completely confused at this point.

Comment: @NoChance I have implemented a new proposal to the design, I don't know if it is a correct proposal though and I can't ask the same question again since it would get marked as a duplicate.

Comment: The lower diagram has a table called "boss-company" but has a fk for employee, so at least the name is misleading. To get the correct information about bosses and companies for  a person, you need to join the intersection table with the boss, employee and company. I am afraid that I can't offer more help off-line. A long discussion is required to get it right. If you have a specific question, then the board would welcome it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97147/discussion-between-learningbyexample-and-nochance).

Comment: What is the question? What is the role of each design? What is "loop the DB"? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please don't include anything unnecessary. Please point out the differences in the designs. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 0):

I just read the question and also it happened few years ago, so I think you already completed it.

My proposal: Why using a table boss and not creating one table of rank and relate it with the occupation relation? It will be more dynamic.

I think you already mastering the modular and dynamic approach of designing the database.