# Getting table names dynamically in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS and I have the following problem: I have the data on another server (MySQL database) and I need to import it into our data warehouse (SQL Server). Source data is specific in terms that I have one main table Surveys, with `surveyID` as PK and for every different survey (depending on product) I have different table (for example `survey_123`, `survey_456 etc`).

I want to dynamically load the data, depending on specific product. So, something like creating variable `@user::survey123` `(select surveyID from surveys where productID = 111)`, and then get the specific data with something like:

```
select * from survey_+@user::survey123.
```

Does anyone have idea how this should be implemented with SSIS? Or if you have some better ideas, feel free to share them with me.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a different table for every product? Why can't you have one survey table with a column that determines which product the survey is for?

Comment: The thing is that in the source database, I have header table Surveys and than basically an indefinite number of tables called survey_123, survey_456, survey_789, where the last three numbers represent the surveyID from the header table for specific product. Data about survey (answers to different questions) is located in the survey_123. I am not sure that I understood how can I achieve this with one survey table with column that determines different products.

Comment: Does `survey_123` have the same structure as `survey_456`?

Comment: Not exactly, the columns are dynamically created depending on questions for that specific survey. To be more concrete, in survey_123 I have columns 123X4X20, 123X4X21, 123X4X22...where last two digits represents the questionID from Questions table, while in survey_456 I have 456X9X40, 456X9X41...In any case thanks for your effort @GarethD, I will appreciate any idea how to solve this.

Comment: Your problem is going to extend to beyond just dynamically selecting the right table, it seems like you are also going to need to dynamically map it, and set the data types. If it is not too late to reconsider your database design I would suggest that you do, [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435) is about database design for surveys so might get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this link. Unfortunately, DB design is not on our side, we just have to take it as it is.

Comment: As far as dynamically setting the table name you can use an expression on the query property of a OLEDB data source and use a variable to hold the table name, but as Gareth has said the real difficulty will be in the fact that the columns are different between tables. Are you intending to get all this data onto one table in your destination or are you going to keep the data in separate tables in the destination as it is in the source?

Comment: Yes that's an excellent point - how are you going to transform this to appear in the target? Depending on what you are doing you should seriously considering storing this in a more normalised format in the target. If you just want to copy the tables across as is you might want to consider using BIML