# Database structure for survey style application

Tags: mysql, database

This question is very similar to this previous question [Database design for a survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey),
however, this asker didn't specify the amount of data they were dealing, the type of data and what they need to do with it and I think this matters quite a bit.

So I've been tasked with adding a survey feature to an application. The application has to deal with 50 distinct organisations, each organisation will have up to 500 surveys. 
Each survey will have up to 150 questions and will store data from true/false, dates etc and all the way up to paragraphs of text. 
Each survey will be answered up to 10,000 times.

I see three main ways of designing the database to cater for this.

1. A single table for all questions, and another for all answers ie.

Questions Table: [ survey_id, question ] etc

Answers Table: [ question_id, answer]

2. A table for each survey, with a field for each question
3. A database for each client... (this is a wild card thrown in by a colleague, I'm very sceptical about this)

Whilst I like the idea of option 1, there are a few issues.
We'll be storing up to 38 billion rows, the answer field would have to be a text field so querying things and sorting by date, for example, is going to be very slow. Real-time reports are going to be expected with this application.

Given the amount of data and reporting requirements, I feel obliged to consider creating the tables dynamically, the data is not subject to change once created due the field it's being used in if a change is required everything is scrapped and started again, so I'm not concerned about having to do schema updates mid-survey. 
The main issue I see with this is the number of tables 25,000 tables seems like an awful lot and I'm not sure if this would be any better than querying 38 billion rows of incorrectly structured data.. or even if there are hard limits I'd likely hit. The one upside here is we can be 100% certain there will not be any table joins and it's unlikely any more than 500 different tables would be assessed in any one day.

Which brings us to option three, this was proposed by a colleague, I'm not sure of the inner working of MySql (the database currently used by the client) but I wouldn't think splitting it to multiple databases would make much / any differences on the same server? Having said that I do have the ability to use any database I wish.

What is the best approach in this scenario and is there a fourth option I've failed to consider?

Comment: Is database size a concern or is it just matter of performance/maintainability? At the moment of entering answer are you able to determine what sort of data shoould be provided eg. if it's a date or numerical value)? Cause I faced similar dilemma like yours (for different case of course) and I solved it using option #1 with a twist. But it may be storage expensive.

Comment: Performance is really my biggest concern. Data types will be  Boolean, Int, dates, times and text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming that your biggest concern is performance and that you actually know what type of data should be the answer I would go with `option #1` but with additional specialized columns.

Keep all the answers as in one table in one general column but add additional columns specific for every type eg. `a_date`, `a_bool`. Fill only general column and the column with the type of data this answer should be. There is very limited number of types and you will be able to set indexes on every one of them and take advantage of their type. The advantage of it is also that you store information about answer type so you can easily focus only on particular answers type eg. dates which can be useful for reporting.

You could also completely separate types in table and instead of having all the answers in one general column and additional per type, you could just have one for text, one for dates and so on. This way you should be able to address open (text) answers and reduce data redundancy in one step.

**Bonus**: For performance gain I would also look into database partitioning eg. using each client (assuming that reporting will be per client).

Answer (score 0):

You could keep paragraph-text answers in a separate table, because of their distinct nature from other question types which will have tiny values. You will need a question-type (or Answer Type?) field for this.

If the questions are totally unique across clients and surveys, or will they be just rehash of "similar looking questions" with different values. If it's the latter the question generation can be made dynamic.

The ideas ('table for each survey'), ('field for each question') and ('a database for each client') look too much denormal to me. A survey-question link table should do. Similarly you could just have a Clients table and have a client-survey link table.

Items of data that are required for real-time reporting can be kept in other tables separately designed for summarized information. Of course, if the question-answer values change after the summary tables are updated, they have to be re-updated to reflect the changed summary values.

This way you won't hit any hard limits. The database can be optimized for real-time reporting, by having additional tables just for reporting elements or counts. Or you could have just one more database, an EIS-like database, for real-time reporting, so that transaction updates don't hinder the reporting and vice versa.

I am well aware that this answer comes from the thinking of 'normalized can still work pretty well' for this scenario, I don't see a case why not.