# EF6 Too Many Navigation Properties Limitation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using E.F 6.2 code first in my MVC project and configure the project for using Asp.Net Identity 2 for accounting. I have a "BaseData" entity, that contains all of my basic data. Here is the class body:

**Parent Entity:**

```
public class BaseData
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Caption { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<A> Children1 { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<B> Children2 { get; set; }

   .

   .

   .

   public virtual ICollection<ZZZ> ChildrenN { get; set; }
}
```

So the other entities must be related to it. In my case, each child entity has hundreds of relations to the "BaseData" parent entity and I have hundreds of child entities. So there is thousands of relations to the parent entity. Here is the pseudo code for child entities:

**Child Entities:**

```
public class A
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int BaseData1Id { get; set; }

   public BaseData BaseData1 { get; set; }

   public int BaseData2Id { get; set; }

   public BaseData BaseData2 { get; set; }

   .
   .
   .

   public int BaseData300Id { get; set; }

   public BaseData BaseData300 { get; set; }
}

.
.
.
.

public class ZZZ
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int BaseData1Id { get; set; }

   public BaseData BaseData1 { get; set; }

   public int BaseData2Id { get; set; }

   public BaseData BaseData2 { get; set; }

   .
   .
   .

   public int BaseData300Id { get; set; }

   public BaseData BaseData300 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using E.F fluent API to configure the relationship between my entities. The problem is that when I run the project and want to fetch some data like user account, I get the "StackOverFlow" exception !!

For solving the problem, I try to remove child entities one by one, and re-creating the database. I found that when the children decreases, the problem is solved and I didn't get exception but I don't know really why !!

Is there limitation for navigation properties on E.F ?
Is there a solution to increase the stack capacity for preventing "StackOverFlow" exception ?

Comment: While I could understand all those collection navigation properties in the `BaseData` entity, why every child entity has all these `BaseEntity` reference navigation properties. This way you are creating N * N relationships with hidden N * (N - 1) collection navigation properties.

Comment: Surely this is a design issue rather than a tool limitation. "Hundreds of relations" can't possibly be right. maybe you should elaborate a bit on aim of this model so we can give some hints how to sanitize it.

Comment: @IvanStoev Suppose that the "BaseData" entity stores feasible answers for a question such as "Yes, No, etc." and child entities are questionnaires that contains many questions and each question has a feasible answer.

Comment: @GertArnold On the situation I explain for Ivan, a question (property) on the child entity, is a foreignKey to the "BaseData" entity that stores one of the feasible answer by Id, so I think that the design is not wrong. I think that the problem is the graph that E.F uses for mapping entity relations, and it is bigger than it could be. Therefore E.F raise an exception that says "StackOverFlow".

Comment: My impression is that all questionnaire should be in one and only one navigation property `Questionaires` to begin with. You're using tables as records.

Comment: @GertArnold No, it cannot be the only one entity "Questionaire" because the questionnaires has different structures from the other and some of the properties on each questionnaire are related to the "BaseAnswer".

Comment: That probably means you didn't abstract a `Questionnaire` well enough. Now it looks like you need a new table each time a new questionnaire is made up. That can't be right.

Comment: Let assume your design is not wrong and the problem is in EF (although we think the opposite). You can't fix EF. So the only options are to keep your design and not use EF, or fix your design.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks a lot for your comments and tips. I do accept that this design is wrong, but my main question is are there any limitations for navigation properties and relationships on E.F ? Suppose that another situation like a very big project in nationwide perspective. Do you mean that E.F is not responsible for limitations such as I faced it ?

Comment: There are no *known* limitations (afaik) on the number of navigation properties you can have in a class, but the question is irrelevant. Design principles stipulate that this number should always be limited because a well-normalized database design will never show huge amounts of foreign keys in *any* table. Also, when an application is "large" it's not uncommon to split it up in aggregates, each having their own specialized context class(es). When this is all in place, the only thing that can go wrong is pulling too many data into memory e.g. by using too many `Include`s.

Comment: Maybe something to put you on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1764435/861716

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks a lot for your tips and comments.

Comment: @VaranSinayee There's probably a limit, I run into a similar problem. I didn't get a stackoverflow error, but EF just quit mapping the rest of the columns. The limit is probably 256 but I can't find any docs to back it up. But my mapping result seem to support that number.

Comment: @RayCheng As I know about the MS-SQL, a table can reference maximum of 253 other tables and columns as foreign keys but this is the MS-SQL limitation. I solved my issues by reducing the number of navigation properties.