# PostgreSQL | How to store user answers in survey?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have task to create survey which aviable only by invitation to certain people. One person can take the survey once. The survey is only available for a specific period of time. I am tring to create database structure for this future application. As database I use PostgreSQL.

As I understand one survey can have many questions. In the same time one question can be reused in many surveys. It's many to many relationship.

Thats how I created tables which solve this first task. Please correct me if I'm somewhere missed or did wrong.

`QUESTIONS`  TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTIONS(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    TEXT TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

`SURVEYS` TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE SURVEYS(
    ID UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION TEXT,
    START_PERIOD TIMESTAMP,
    END_PERIOD TIMESTAMP
);
```

`SURVEYS_QUESTIONS` TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE SURVEYS_QUESTIONS(
    ID SERIAL,
    SURVEY_ID UUID NOT NULL,
    QUESTION_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SURVEY_ID) REFERENCES SURVEYS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (QUESTION_ID) REFERENCES QUESTIONS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Right now I don't understand how correctly connect users with surveys and how correctly store user answers.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `TAKEN_SURVEYS` table with a foreign key to the `SURVEYS` table and a foreign key to the `USERS` table.  If you want to ensure there can be only one taken survey record per user, create a unique index on the `TAKEN_SURVEYS` table.

Comment: Hello! Thank you! I steal don't understand how looks like my final database structure. In StackOverflowI found [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764901/4332480) . What do you think about that structure presented in the answer?

Comment: Something like that.  It's similar to what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing your last table with two new tables. This would align with classic 101 example of Customers-Orders-Products (here being Users-Surveys-Q&A).

```
CREATE TABLE USER_SURVEYS (
    ID SERIAL,
    USER_ID UUID NOT NULL,
    SURVEY_ID UUID NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (SURVEY_ID) REFERENCES SURVEYS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE USER_SURVEYS_QA (
    ID SERIAL,
    USER_SURVEY_ID INT NOT NULL,
    QUESTION_ID INT NOT NULL,
    ANSWER VARCHAR(255),
    OTHER_SPECIFY VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_SURVEY_ID) REFERENCES USER_SURVEYS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (QUESTION_ID) REFERENCES QUESTIONS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. So finally as I understand I need to decline `SURVEYS_QUESTIONS` table which I proposed, right? Instead of that table I need to create your 2 table, right? So what will be the final structure? Just from 4 table?

Comment: First, there is no right or wrong with database design. It is more an art than science. You should always aim for normalization and referential integrity but align to how your application, systems, teams need to access the data. This solution is only *one* way. With more background of your entire needs, the right schema can be cultivated: What is your organization? What type of survey? How are surveys designed and managed? How do users take your surveys? What type of questions (e.g., multiple-choice) /answers (e.g., open-ended)?