# Survey Database - additional question about table structure

Tags: structure, survey

I'm referencing a closed stack overflow post,

[Database design for a survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey)

The top answer in the post gives a great overview of the tables to use for a survey database, with a good table-relationship view.  My question piggybacks on the survey tables, particularly the table which stores the top level survey records.  For surveys which are given in specified periods (initial survey, 6 month after, 12 month after, etc.), if the survey does not have different questions and answers (just a duplicate of the initial survey), would it make more sense to create different surveys in the top level survey table as different survey records, or would it be better to add a field in the completed survey table as a secondary identifier.

For example, if a survey (let's call it "Health assessment") has an initial survey, then one 6 month after, which would be the better solution:

- make two records in the survey table - "Health assessment - initial" and "Health assessment - 6 month", so that in the completed survey table the surveyID would be different for both surveys.  This would, I suppose, require records for both surveys in other tables (survey_question and survey_question_answer).  Seems like a lot of duplication.
- make one record in the survey table - "Health assessment", and add an additional designation in the completed survey table (answer) where the user could put "Initial" or "6-month".

Hopefully that makes sense.  I think either solution might work; I just want the more optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping to this existing design; Assuming SurveyID is a unique Primary Key, the first suggestion, as you already recognized, will cause redundant data unless the intention is for the questions to change over time. The second option is not great either because I believe it would invalidate the purpose of the StartDate, EndDate, and IsOpened fields on the Survey table.

What about creating a Survey_Instance table? The Survey table would hold the Survey ID and description and the new table would hold the Start, End, and IsOpened properties for each time the survey posted. The responses could be linked via "SurveyInstanceID" and the questions could be linked to the Survey table. This has the added benefit of linking responses to a specific time frame so you could observe how the responses might change over time.

Comment: Isn't the survey instance really the Answer table record with an added date field?  I was mulling over what you posted and thought that, perhaps, a Survey Type might be an alternate solution as well.  Type could be initial survey, 6 month after, 12 month after, etc, and I could add the type to each survey completed.  Thoughts?

Comment: An extra column on the Answer table and the "Survey_Instance" table, as I described, would accomplish the same thing, yes. However, with the "Survey_Instance" table, you would have a single row that identifies what survey it was and the duration of it. If you moved the date information to the Answers table then the Start and End of the instance would have to be replicated for every question asked. Two date time values vs twenty datetime values on an instance of a survey that has 10 questions. Furthermore, given the schema you suggest, where would the IsOpen column logically reside?