# Verifying success or failure of various API calls - Angular 9, DjangoREST

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, rxjs

First some context, I coded together a "form generator" much like Google Forms for internal use at a company that runs several types of surveys, which are all in question/answer format. The DB design is very functionally similar to this [image: DB ER] (taken from [Database design for a survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey))

The backend is written in Python using Django and Django Rest Framework, frontend is Angular 9. Some questions are more complex than what Google Forms permits per the company's needs, for example, some questions permit more than one answer, certain answers have "secondary questions" associated to them and other questions are dependant on certain answers (i.e. some questions must be disabled if a certain answer is not selected)

Due to the complexity of the database and mostly to my general lack of experience, my solution in the frontend to be able to POST to the API seems hacky to me. The insert logic is as follows:

1. Survey is created
2. Survey_Question is created (question is pulled from a special type of pre-existing "template" survey)
3. Depending on the TYPE of Survey_Question (single answer, multiple answer etc) one or several Survey_Question_Answers are created (OfferedAnswer is also pulled from special template)

Person and Answer tables are not used in my design

The basic idea of the way this is coded in Angular is as follows:

```
this.createSurvey().subscribe(survey => {
    this.questions.forEach(question => {
        question.survey = survey
        this.createQuestion(question).subscribe(newQuestion => {
            // same logic with answers that belong to this question
        })
    )}
})
```

This is the basic gist of the insert logic. As I am in a learn as I code process, at this point I have come to believe that nesting subscriptions this way is not recommended, even though I have extracted them to methods to prevent visual "call-back hell". Although functional, I am now faced with the problem of having no idea how to emit a single "Form successfully saved" message to the user after every question has been successfully created via POST since there is no particular sequence (to my understanding) when using async calls this way.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, where to read or what operators belonging to RXJS were/are appropriate for these types of tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You avoid callback hell by chaining with `switchMap` here, and `forkJoin` all the create question request in parallel

```
this.createSurvey().pipe(switchMap(survey=>
 forkJoin(this.questions.map(question => {
        question.survey = survey
        return this.createQuestion(question)
 }))
).subscribe(e=>success action....)
```