# Inserting command in one to many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-insert

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764901/13670488

according to the solution in the link, can the user insert 3 questions with their answers at the same time? how?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`insert` will take multiple rows. For example.

```
-- Person 10 answered survey 5.
-- Question 1 they picked Offered Answer 3
-- Question 2 they picked Offered Answer 6
-- Question 3 they picked Offered Answer 7
insert into answer (SurveyID, QuestionID, OfferedAnswerID, PersonID)
  values (5, 1, 3, 10), (5, 2, 6, 10), (5, 3, 7, 10);
```